# How to implement 2 different lists with 2 different ITEMS in a single listView with a sectional divider between the listView?

Tags: android, listview

I want to implement a listView with 2 different lists which is using 2 different Items and want to display them using a same ListView.

1. Both lists are separated with a sectional divider
2. The above listView is having a custom selector imageButton in the item
3. below listView has dateDividers for their items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge
```

in order to create and merge different adapters with the data you need. You should also insert a header view.

Here follows an example:

```
@BindView(R.id.lv_validation_errors)
ListView lvValidationErrors;

private List<Notification> notificationList = new ArrayList<>();

public MergeAdapter mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();

public ArrayAdapter errorAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayAdapter alertAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> alertList = new ArrayList<>();
```

First I set the ListView (using ButterKnife, which does the findViewById stuff) then

```
errorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_error, R.id.text1, errorList);
mergeAdapter.addView(header("Erros"), false);
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(errorAdapter);
```

I created the adapters I want to mmerge and added the view for the section header (dont forget to set a value to your list to prevent it from being null) then

```
 alertAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_warning, R.id.text1, alertList);
 mergeAdapter.addView(header("Advertências"), false);
 mergeAdapter.addAdapter(alertAdapter);
```

same as the previous step and finally:

```
lvValidationErrors.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```

to set the merged adapter to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to take one list with type `Object`

```
List<Object> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

your both different list values add in above `listItems` .

then after bind your adapter with `listItems` and when you bind your item in your `BindView()` write like below.

```
if(listItems instanceof firstListItemModel)
  // bind item from your first list
else if(listItems instanceof secondListItemModel)
// bind item from your second list
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand, you want a vertically half divided screen with containing `ListView` in each of them.
And you are saying that bottom `ListView` is completely based on upper `ListView`.

bottom ListView should load according to Upper `ListView` selection.

if **Yes**, then you can use weight to show both`ListViews`*(upper and bottom)* on layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can take set Adapter on `list_view2` on `list_view1` item click :

```
ListView upperListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view1);
ListView bottomListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view2);

      upperListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // You can put your logic here to fetch data according to upper ListView item clicked position. I am taking temp. data for now.
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList//your desired list here);
                    ((ListView) bottomListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
```

That's it!!